# PhoneGap - Building phonegap android app gives compile error on Linux

Tags: android, linux, node.js, cordova

I am getting error while building phonegap android app on my linux (ubuntu 12.04) machine.
I have installed nodejs, set JAVA_HOME, ANT_HOME, ANDROID_HOME vars and $JAVA_HOME/bin, $ANT_HOME/bin, $ANDROID_HOME/tools, $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools to the path. when I am running command `phonegap local build android`, I am getting following error:

```
ME@My-PC:/dos/PhoneGap/HelloWorld$ phonegap local run android 
[phonegap] compiling Android...
    [error] An error occurred while building the android project. 
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'shelljs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/dos/PhoneGap/HelloWorld/platforms/android/cordova/lib/build.js:22:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Thanks for Helping

Comment: Did you run `npm install phonegap` to install all of the dependencies, like shelljs?

Comment: @MBillau yes i have installed phonegap by this command

Comment: Have you tried "$ phonegap build android
"? As you tried "$ phonegap local build android"?

Comment: @Amit Gupta, I want it to build locally.

Comment: What is your path? Is it really `ME@My-PC:/dos/...`? Maybe there are problems with the hyphen in `My-PC`? I know there have been problems with spaces and hyphens before...

Answer (score 36):

you must

```
$cordova platform remove android

$cordova platform add android
```

because there is directory is missing in

platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/shelljs

or you can create another app and copy the missing file and add it in your app

**Recently solution**

in terminal go to your app
then

```
cd platforms/android/cordova
sudo npm install shelljs
```

it's working fine with me

Comment: removing the platforms/android directory is not a solution for me

Comment: @bjunix ok you can download shelljs >>>> in terminal go to your app then cd  platforms/android/cordova >>>>> then sudo npm install shelljs

Comment: @bjunix I ran the command, and saw that shelljs was installed too. But didn't work util I ran `npm install -g phonegap` (Windows).

Comment: ran into this pb because of stupid node_modules/ in .gitignore
... saved my day, thanks !

Answer (score 7):

I already installed shelljs:

```
sudo npm install shelljs -g
```

But I needed to set NODE_PATH

```
export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Not sure why it was missing...

Comment: Great mate, the problem was the NODE_PATH, that worked for me, thanks!

Comment: I was getting "Missing Q module" error. NODE_PATH didn't work for me but appending to path solved everything. (export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

Answer (score 2):

I have needed to update *cordova-android* engine (from 3.5.1) to 3.6.0 (because required by the splashscreen plugin, [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/master/plugin.xml#L32))

To build the Android project (and evict the above errors), i have added in the `package.json` file (of my Cordova project root folder), the following *npm* dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "q": "^1.2.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.4.0",
    "which": "^1.0.9"
  }
```

Comment: I had the same issue and this was the solution, maybe this should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the exact same error message on OS X 10.9 for my phonegap android app.  The problem was that I set my `JAVA_HOME` variable incorrectly.  Once it was correct, I needed to remove and add the android platform in cordova.  It is possible that this may be your issue, so this is how I fixed it:

In my .zshrc file added the line `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

Finally I had to remove the platform and add it again in order for cordova to properly utilize java.

$`cordova platform remove android`

$`cordova platform add android`

Note: While troubleshooting, I installed the [JDK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html), which may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to ensure the required libs are installed running:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova gulp
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was with directory and user permissions. I created the project in home directory, and it was working.