# Cannot find module 'which' - Cordova android

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to build my cordova build by executing below command

```
cordova -d build android
```

but I am necountering below error.

```
module.js:340
throw err;                                                                                                       
Error: Cannot find module 'which'                              
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)     
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)                
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)                       
at require (module.js:380:17)
```

anyone knows the reason?  I checked that I have my ANT_HOME/ANDROID_HOME in my path but I am not sure what is the reason behind the error though.

I am running windows 7 64 bit by the way

Comment: Any updates? Would love to see an answer for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Similar to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592701/phonegap-building-phonegap-android-app-gives-compile-error-on-linux), the solution for me was to

```
$cordova platform remove android
$cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like some kind of missing node module to me.. Have you tried:

```
npm install -g which
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your nodejs installation is broken. It occurs when install/update from yum (for sample) failed.
For my case, I simply deleted the broken modules from "/usr/lib/node_modules" and perfomed an install.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today, too.
I installed `which` but then the module `chalk` was missing.

Doing an `npm update` installed all the packages missing and it seems to be the right way to resolve. (But why this happened is a mystery as `node` was doing fine yesterday and I cannot recall any relevant changes.)